# How can i call a typescript method into javascript

Tags: typescript

How can i call a typescript method into JavaScript.

```
function showAlert(event){

      // here i want to call a typescript method
}
```

Comment: I think you can start using the Playground first. It will help you to understand better both languages: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in calling typescript from javascript. You can do this as usual you do in javascript to javascript. Please provide more detail